# Can you say that a something meets certain limitations?

Tags: collocations

I couldn't find the phrase in any collocation dictionaries, but it does seem to be used occasionally, according to Google.

For example:
"Make sure that the configuration meets the following limitations."

Comment: We normally say of work done in accordance with strict specifications / constraints that it ***meets*** the relevant ***criteria / specifications*** OR ***observes / honours / adheres to*** the relevant ***limitations / constraints.*** The former category being primarily concerned with things it ***must*** do, the latter with things it ***mustn't / can't*** do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the word you might be looking for is "criteria", not "limitations", although it's hard to tell for certain without more context.  To "meet the following criteria" is a common collocation.

I've never heard anyone say "meet the following limitations", and to me it doesn't really make sense because a limitation is not something you would generally apply to something, rather a limit beyond which something will no longer work, and which can't be exceeded, or more generally, something which cannot be done.

Perhaps if you really do mean limitation, you might want to reword it. "Make sure that the configuration takes the following limitations into account", or "Make sure that the configuration does not exceed the following limits".

Comment: or "Make sure that the configuration fulfills the following limitations", where *fulfill* may be replaced by *adhere to* or *comply with*.